# Construção de graficos

Tags: php, javascript

Tenho a seguinte questão como posso inserir código `php` dentro do `javascript`, ou seja tenho um gráfico feito em `JS` e quero que o mesmo seja baseado em dados da minha base de dados, como colocar o `php` dentro do `js` ou tenho de ir buscar a informação da base de dados a partir do JS?

Por exemplo a em baixo tenho aa parte do código em que pretende preencher os pontos no eixo dos Y e eu pretendo em vez de ter valor preencher com valores da base de dados já efectuei o select  mas como faço para colocar em vez dos valores um ciclo while que percorre uma tabela ada base de dados e insira os valores.

data:[1,5000,15000,18394,18287,28682,31274,33259,25849,24159,32651,31984,38451]

Comment: sua pergunta está confusa, por favor edite a mesma e insira trechos do código para que possamos analisar e te ajudar, veja como fazer uma boa pergunta [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas).

Comment: Achei a sua pergunta confusa. O seu problema é fazer o Javascript baixar dados que são dados pelo PHP e com isso montar um gráfico?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cara, você pode utilizar um laço de repetição com o php dentro do javascript, a única coisa que precisa fazer é abrir a tag do php dentro do js quando você for utilizar ele.

Ex passar variavel PHP para js

```
<?php  
$conteudo = 'testando';  
?>
<script>
   var conteudo_js = "<?php echo $conteudo; ?>";
   alert(conteudo_js);
</script>
```

Ex passando For

```
<?php  
   $array_conteudo = array('conteudo1','conteudo2','conteudo3');
?>
<script>
var conteudo_js = '';
<?php  
  foreach($array_conteudo as $val)
  {
?>
  alert("<?php echo $val; ?>");
<?php
  }
?>
</script>
```

Comment: Eu ja tentei isso mas nao consegui eu sou novo em php e por isso que tambem estou a ter dificuldades mas ent nao escreve apenas ponho a variavel?

Comment: Editei a resposta

Comment: Ah ok, ja precebi o que estava a fazer mal eu estava a meter a tag diretamente de php bastava igualar a uma variavel de js muito obrigado é isso mesmo!!